# rdlc error on webserver, missing files? web.config?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, rdlc

I developed a webpage generating QR codes which are sent to a reportviewer in code, aiming to render to pdf and/or excel.
The code works fine on my development machine, but it errors on rendering when I upload to the IIS webserver.

Before that I had errors on the reportviewer dll's. I solved that by placing these 4 files in the bin folder:

```
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll 
Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Webforms.dll
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Winforms.dll
```

These files were not in the server's GAC although .NET 4.5 is installed. I'm aiming .NET 4.0 (version 11 of the dll's)

Am I maybe missing another file used for export to excel.pdf?

The exception I get is: error during local report processing.
with an inner exception: The definition of the report 'myreport.rdlc' is invalid.

Or do I need to add something in the web.config? As I said it works fine on my development machine.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a Classic ASP question - could you remove that tag, please?

Comment: As I test I placed the reportviewer on the form, to show the report there. In that reportviewer I got a message about missing Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll

So I copied that as well in the bin folder and now the report on form as well as the export to pdf/excel work. 

I'm not even using SQL server in that report!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not installed reportviewer on web server

look here

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747

or here

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6442

depending on what version you need.